# Gulp - optipng throws error

Tags: google-app-engine, gulp, roots-sage

Running gulp to build my project.

Throws error:

```
[14:35:01] Starting 'images'...

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn X\node_modules\optipng-bin\vendor\optipng.exe ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Currently installed OptiPNG version 0.7.6

Not sure what to check or do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution was to delete `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again.